# Cómo puedo hacer que mi parámetro lea más de un valor en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado para saber las fechas futuras en las que se hace el mantenimiento de cada máquina, pero son muchas máquinas, necesito que tome como valor cada máquina y aplique el ciclo, pero sólo llama una máquina.

Los Declare que uso, son para que me llame los datos de la máquina para así poder realizar el ciclo y saber cuando sera el próximo mantenimiento dentro del rango de la fecha que le doy.

```
@name varchar(50),
                    @FechaHasta datetime,
                    @Result     DATETIME = null OUTPUT)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @JOBNO NVARCHAR(50)
        SELECT  @JOBNO = JOBNO FROM PMMASTER INNER JOIN LABORMP 
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID INNER JOIN PMMSCHEDULE
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID 
        where EMPLOYEENAME = @name AND PMMSCHEDULE.CYCLETYPE =2 and PMMSCHEDULE.SETTING2 IS NOT NULL and PMMSCHEDULE.SETTING1 IS NOT NULL

        DECLARE @DATELAST DATETIME
            SELECT @DATELAST = DATELAST FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
            WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO) and EMPLOYEENAME =@name 

        DECLARE @SETTING1 INT
            SELECT @SETTING1 = SETTING1 FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
            WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO)  AND EMPLOYEENAME = @name 

            DECLARE @SETTING2 INT
            SELECT @SETTING2 = SETTING2 FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
            ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
            WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO)  AND EMPLOYEENAME = @name 

DECLARE
    @DateFirst  INT
SELECT  @DateFirst  =   @@DateFirst

/* Today */ 
DECLARE 
        @TodaysDate     DATETIME    
-- Finding today's date after resetting the time to midnight 
SELECT  @TodaysDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101), 101) 

/* Todays WeekDay */ 
DECLARE
    @TodaysWeekDay  INT
SELECT  @TodaysWeekDay  =   DATEPART(dw, @TodaysDate)

/* Selected WeekDay */ 
DECLARE 
    @WeekDay    INT 
SELECT  @WeekDay    =   CHARINDEX('1',  @Setting2) 

/* Schedule Date */ 
DECLARE
        @ScheduleDate   DATETIME 
-- Find the starting schedule date. If the schedule date is in a previous  
-- week, adjust to the most recent week in the schedule 
SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   @DATELAST 

-- Adjust scheduled date to closest possible week day
SELECT  @ScheduleDate = DATEADD(dd, @WeekDay - DATEPART(dw, @ScheduleDate), @ScheduleDate)

-- Add cycles until a possible date is met  
WHILE   (@ScheduleDate  <   @TodaysDate)
    SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(wk, @Setting1, @ScheduleDate)

IF  (@ScheduleDate  <=  @DATELAST)
    SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(wk, @Setting1, @ScheduleDate)

SELECT  @Result =   @ScheduleDate

SELECT @Result AS RESULTADO

SET DATEFIRST   @DateFirst


WHILE(@Result <@FechaHasta)
    BEGIN
        IF(@Result <@FechaHasta)

            SELECT  @Result =   DATEADD(WK, @Setting1,  @Result)
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [00TblFecha] ON 

            INSERT INTO dbo.[00TblFecha](idFecha,jobno,fecha)VALUES(3,@JOBNO,@Result)

            SET IDENTITY_INSERT[00TblFecha] OFF     
            print @Result
        end
```

Comment: Podrias pegar el código completo del create procedure, no parece el inicio correcto de una sentencia lo que has puesto ?

Comment: Creería que lo que necesitas es colocar ese procedimiento dentro de un bucle que recorra todas las máquinas y a partir de ahí obtener la información de cada una de ellas una por una... . Otra opción sería un bucle en el sql, algo que no es recomendado, o una función y un select, pero para poder aterrizar una mejor respuesta deberías colocar la estructura de las tablas involucradas y un resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Hola respecto a tu pregunta no logro identificar lo que buscas, pero para apoyarte y crear más de un parámetro, debes trabajar con SQL Dinámicos (con los EXEC), te pongo un ejemplo simple para que puedas identificar que dentro de un SP puedas ejecutar un parámetro de crear una tabla:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Agrega_Tabla
@nomtabla VARCHAR (20) 
AS
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE TABLE '+ @nomtabla +'(
    ruc char(11),                                                                                           
    razon_social varchar(200),
    categoria_fact_real varchar(3),
    direccion varchar(255),
    ciudad varchar(50),
    estado char(1),
    Outsourcing_a_cargo char(30),
)')
END
GO
```

Link de referencia:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html